# Unable to locate element whose xpath contains lots 'div'

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate an element that is a simple message (not a hyperlink) inside a chatbot. I tried to get xpath using 'inspect' and tried this -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//[@id='app']/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/speak").text
```

This works but this is not a reliable solution. I tried to shorten xpath using starts-with or contains but dint worked.

Is there any other locator other than xpath that I can use when there are lots of 'div' in xpath? What does this means in xpath above

```
[@id='app']
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to write custom xpath instead of generate it by browser.
It will looks like `"//[@id='app']//speak"`.